# Why does Datagrip say user/pass wrong when they work in Tableplus?

Tags: sql-server, datagrip, table-plus

I have Tableplus and it it connects and runs queries on a SQL Server database just fine.

When I replicate those connection settings exactly in Datagrip, it fails to connect and complains the username and password are incorrect. I have tried several times and been very thorough in checking that I'm entering the exact same usernames and passwords into both.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: A screenshot of both connection windows will be useful here

Answer (score 0):

can you share a little more in-terms of what you're entering in the other places. I use DataGrip for SS as well. I enter the IP for Host, port, then username and password without assigning the username to any instance something\username <-- ex, password obviously. Doublecheck the Database field, you can just leave it blank, it might be trying to route you to a specific database that those credentials don't have access to, so try either leaving it blank, or assigning it specifically. Then make sure the URL in the last box lines up with what you entered, sometimes it doesn't ... oddly enough.